# Return unique map values in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Hello I have a situation where I have list of rights(List of Permission) and I need to convert this list into map Map< String, List of Permission>. In map, key is 'type' and same object will be inserted into corresponding list value.I wrote code which is working perfectly fine but it is storing duplicate Permission objects. I need to store unique object into list. How can I achieve this. Current code is below which is storing duplicate object in list:

```
listofRights  
        .stream()  
        .filter(permission-> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(permission.getType()))  
        .collect(Collectors  
            .groupingBy(Permission::getRole,  
                Collectors.mapping(identity(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate rows"?

Comment: I *guess* you would need `Collectors.toSet()` instead of `Collectors.toList()`; but just guessing here

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(Permission::getRole,  
                Collectors.mapping(identity(), Collectors.toList()))` can simply be `Collectors.groupingBy(Permission::getRole)`. also, be more specific.

Comment: What are the types of `listofRights`, `a`, and `Permission`?

Comment: @intentionally listofRights has objects of type Permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to change `Collectors.toList()` with `Collectors.toSet()`, assuming `Permission` implements `equals/hashCode`

Comment: It did not solve the issue.. I have used Collectors.toSet() now and Info object Permission is implementing EqualsAndHashCode too but still duplicate info objects are returning

Comment: @R.Ali duplicates where? You have not provided any meaningful details

Comment: question is updated! I need to return map(Map<String, Set<Permission>>) and I need unique objects in Set.. Used Set as you suggested

Comment: Hey It worked! I have inner classes and @EqualsAndHashCodewas using for outer class

Comment: please confirm one thing, above code will maintain order ?

Comment: @R.Ali it will not. There's a `groupingBy` variant that you can supply the type of the `Map`, if you need order thus use `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: How can I supply type of Map to groupingBy variant ?

Comment: @R.Ali how about you start reading the documentation? Seriously this is a very simple change! `Collectors.groupingBy(Function, LinkedHashMap::new, Collector )`. `Function` and `Collector` does not change from the one already in the code...